# How to detect changes in a datagridview row?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview with 15 columns.
The rows are filled from it, what I want is an event, function or method to **detect the change in the rows** (not in cells).

I tried:

```cs
private void DGVPurchases_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (DGVPurchases.RowCount > 0)
        {
            switch (DGVPurchases.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name)
            {
                case "PurchaseEmisionDate":
                case "PurchaseVendorNumber":
                //others columns
                    if (!Convert.ToBoolean(DGVPurchases.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["PurchaseModified"].Value))
                            DGVPurchases.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["PurchaseModified"].Value = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception er)
    {
        PBLog.Save(this, er);
        Alert.Error(Error.Value, App.Purchase.Title);
    }
}
```

`PurchaseModified` is a checkbox type column that when detecting changes in cells is set to true, but it does not work quite well since the CellValueChanged event only fires when the cell leaves edit mode or the focus is changed to another cell.

Comment: Do you use data binding?

Comment: Problem solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use: DataGridView.RowValidating and DataGridView.RowValidated.for example:

```
private void DGVPurchases_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    cellTextBox = e.Control as TextBox;
    if (cellTextBox != null)
        cellTextBox.TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged;
}
private void DGVPurchases_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
    originalValue = DGVPurchases[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;
}
private void DGVPurchases_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (cellTextBox != null)
        cellTextBox.TextChanged -= TextBox_TextChanged;
}
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DGVPurchases["PurchaseModified", rowIndex].Value =
        cellTextBox.Text != originalValue.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess [`RowDirtyStateNeeded`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowdirtystateneeded?view=net-5.0) is what you are looking for. Set the DataGridView's `VirtualMode` property to true and add `RowDirtyStateNeeded` handler. When the event is fired, check if `QuestionEventArgs`.`Respose` is true.

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe DataGridView to events:

```
DGVPurchases.EditingControlShowing += DGVPurchases_EditingControlShowing;
DGVPurchases.CellBeginEdit += DGVPurchases_CellBeginEdit;
DGVPurchases.CellEndEdit += DGVPurchases_CellEndEdit;
```

Define the fields in the form:

```
private int rowIndex;
private object originalValue;
private TextBox cellTextBox;
```

Implement event handlers:

```
private void DGVPurchases_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    cellTextBox = e.Control as TextBox;
    if (cellTextBox != null)
        cellTextBox.TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged;
}
private void DGVPurchases_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
    originalValue = DGVPurchases[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;
}
private void DGVPurchases_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (cellTextBox != null)
        cellTextBox.TextChanged -= TextBox_TextChanged;
}
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DGVPurchases["PurchaseModified", rowIndex].Value =
        cellTextBox.Text != originalValue.ToString();
}
```

Modify behavior as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

> what I want is an event, function or method to detect the change in the rows

Do you want to be notified as soon as the operator finishes editing one or more cells in a row and selects a different row to edit? In that case use events `DataGridView.RowValidating` and `DataGridView.RowValidated`.

Not sure though it that would be a nice interface. Suppose half-way typing the customer's address the operator decides to copy-paste it from the text editor he has on his screen?

I think a good HMI is, that you let the operator do his task in all his peace, and you should start processing the edits only when the operator indicates that he finished editing the DataGridView.

To be able to see all changes:

Using visual studio designer you will probably have added columns. You'll need to specify which column should show which property:

```
class DisplayedPurchase
{
    public int Id {set; set;}
    public DateTime EmisionDate {get; set;}
    public int VendorNumber {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

Probably in your constructor:

```
public MyForm() : base()
{
    InitializeComponents();

    this.columnId.DataPropertyName = nameof(DisplayedPurchase.Id);
    this.columnEmissionDate.DataPropertyName = nameof(DisplayedPurchase.EmissionDate);
    this.columnVendorNumber.DataPropertyName = nameof(DisplayedPurchase.VendorNumber);
    ...
}
```

You need a procedure to fetch the Purchases that must be displayed (out of scope of this question)

```
public IEnumerable<DisplayedPurchase> FetchPurchases(...)
{
    ...
}
```

To Display the Purchases and to know about the changes: use a BindingList:

```
BindingList<DisplayedPurchase> DisplayedPurchases
{
    get => (BindingList<DisplayedPurchase>)this.dataGridView1.DataSource;
    set => this.dataGridView1.DataSource = value;
}
```

To initialize the datagrid view:

```
private void InitDisplayedPurchases()
{
    this.DisplayedPurchases = new BindingList<DisplayedPurchase>(
        this.FetchPurchases(...).ToList());
}

private void OnFormLoading(object sender, ...)
{
    this.InitDisplayedPurchases();
}
```

Now Suppose you decided that the operator clicks the Apply-Now button to notify that the edited data must be processed.

```
private void OnButtonApplyNow_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    ICollection<DisplayedPurchase> editedPurchases = this.DisplayedPurchases;
    // find out which data is changed and process them
    this.ProcessEditedPurchases(editedPurchases);
}
```

Because you put all data in a BindingList, all added / removed / changed rows are automatically in `this.DisplayedPurchases`.

You might also be interested in the current DisplayedPurchase and the selected DisplayedPurchases (if multi-select)

```
DisplayedPurchase CurrentDisplayedPurchase => (DislayedPurchase)
    this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow?.DataBoundItem;

IEnumerable<DisplayedPurchase> SelectedPurchases => this.datGridView1.SelectedRows
    .Cast<DatGridViewRow>()
    .Select(row => row.DataBoundItem)
    .Cast<DisplayedPurchase>();
```

If you really want to process rows immediately after they are edited, consider to subscribe to events RowValidating and RowValidated:

```
public void OnRowValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dataGridView = (DataGridView)sender;
    DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    DisplayedPurchase editedPurchase = (DisplayedPurchase)(row.DataBoundItem);
    this.ProcessEditedPurchase(editedPurchase);
}
```